# Executing a form after animation is done JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to submit the form only after my animation is done and completed

Code ------> http://pastie.org/5109573

```
<form action='loginn.php' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>
        <label for='username'>Username*:</label>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50"
        />
        <label for='password'>Password*:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password'
        maxlength="50" /> <a><input class ="animated" type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' /></a>

    </fieldset>
</form> 
<span></span>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $("form").submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($("input:first").val() == "correct") {
            $("span").text("OKAY :D").show().fadeOut(1000);
            $("a").addClass('animated hinge');

            $("span").promise().done(function () {
                return true;
            });

        } else {
            $("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
            return false;
        }   
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

The form gets submitted before the animation is complete !

Comment: Please include the code in your question. Try to keep it down to only the most relevant lines (5-10 lines is a good rule of thumb).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely here:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
```

You're not declaring `event`. Try this:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
```

### Edit:

Also, the function you're passing to the `done()` method doesn't do anything. Returning `true` from that function won't affect the event; in fact, the event is already handled and gone by the time that function runs.

If you're trying to submit the form with your `done` callback, you need to do it explicitly. To avoid an infinite loop when it submits again, try specifying a namespace:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    var that = this;
    if (event.namespace != 'verified') {
         event.preventDefault();
         if ($("input:first").val() == "correct") {
              $("span").promise().done(function () {
                   $(that).trigger('submit.verified');
              });
         }  else {  
             $("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);                             
             return false;
         }
    } 
});​
```

Comment: Now it does not submit the form, only does the animation and stops

Comment: I'm trying to use the jQuery .promise() function to return true so that the form will submit AFTER the animation is done

Comment: Found a workaround by separating the submit function and the submit button..

The button when clicked calls the submit function....

Comment: @Xandu6a - You mean the edited code didn't work? It works for me. What if you want to use more than one control to submit the same form?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the animations callback function to submit the form when the animation completes, like so:

```
$("input[name='Submit']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    if ($("input:first").val() == "correct") {
        $("span").text("OKAY :D").show().fadeOut(1000, function() {
            form.submit();
        });
        $("a").addClass('animated hinge');
    } else {
        $("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
    }
});​
```

Comment: This will trigger an infinite loop.

Comment: It did trigger an infinite loop.

Comment: And i did change it around 15 minutes ago ?